# How to implement rustc_serialize::Decodable for struct that has a field value that is another struct?

Tags: struct, rust

I need to implement the `rustc_serialize::Decoder` trait for my `Herd` struct:

```
extern crate chrono;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use chrono::NaiveDate;
use rustc_serialize::Decodable;

struct Herd {
    id: i32,
    breed: String,
    name: String,
    purchase_date: NaiveDate,
}

impl Decodable for Herd {
    fn decode<D: Decoder>(d: &mut D) -> Result<Herd, D::Error> {
        d.read_struct("Herd", 4, |d| {
            let id = try!(d.read_struct_field("id", 0, |d| d.read_i32()));
            let breed = try!(d.read_struct_field("breed", 1, |d| d.read_str()));
            let name = try!(d.read_struct_field("name", 2, |d| d.read_str()));
            let purchase_date = try!(d.read_struct_field("purchase_date", 3, |i| {
                i.read_struct("NaiveDate", 1, |i| {
                    let ymdf = try!(i.read_struct_field("ymdf", 0, |i| i.read_i32()));
                    Ok(NaiveDate { ymdf: ymdf })
                })
            }));

            Ok(Herd {
                id: id,
                breed: breed,
                name: name,
                purchase_date: purchase_date,
            })
        })
    }
}
```

I'm unable to use `#[derive(RustcDecodable)]` because the following error occurs:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound chrono::NaiveDate: rustc_serialize::Decodable is not satisfied
```

I'm working on manually implementing `Decodable` and that's what you see in the code above. [`NaiveDate` from the rust-chrono crate](https://github.com/lifthrasiir/rust-chrono/blob/2dea325524c23c47d1172c75fee1da5dd05210af/src/naive/date.rs#L97) is a struct with one field that is of data type `i32`.

When I run the code right now, I receive the message:

> field ymdf of struct chrono::NaiveDate is private

How do I implement `Decoder` for `NaiveDate`? Is there a simpler way to implement `Decodable` for my `Herd` struct? I am an all-around beginner programmer; perhaps there is another way to look at this problem.

I am using Rust 1.12 with the following dependencies:

- `nickel = "0.9.0"`
- `postgres = { version = "0.12", features = ["with-chrono"]}`
- `chrono = "0.2"`
- `rustc-serialize = "0.3"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NaiveDate` does implement `Decodable` but under an optional feature `"rustc-serialize"`.

You should add this in your `Cargo.toml` to activate it:

```
chrono = { version = "0.2", features = ["rustc-serialize"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to `derive` `Decodable` for `Herd`, `NaiveDate` would need to be `Decodable` too. Its `ymdf` field is private, though, which is an issue if you wanted to implement it manually.

What you could do is define your own wrapper type for `ymdf` (and use it in `Herd`) - then you should be able to `derive` `Decodable` for it and then for `Herd`.

**Edit**: It's not necessarily the way to go with `NaiveDate`, as there is no easy way to convert `ymdf` into it (or to import `DateImpl`, its type), but depending on your needs the following way might be enough:

```
use std::i32;

pub type DateImpl = i32;
pub const MAX_YEAR: DateImpl = i32::MAX >> 13;
pub const MIN_YEAR: DateImpl = i32::MIN >> 13;

#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct YmdfWrapper {
    ymdf: DateImpl
}

#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct Herd {
    id: i32,
    breed: String,
    name: String,
    purchase_date: YmdfWrapper,
}
```

Comment: To implement `Decodable`, `Herd` does not need all its fields to be `Decodable`. That's only required when you want to derive a trait. In such cases it would just be easier to implement the trait manually.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if it showed a snippet of how to do this. It would also be the only answer to answer the general question posed by OP, not the specific instance ^_^

Comment: @Shepmaster I'd like to, but [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39220694/cargo-on-windows-behind-a-corporate-proxy) makes it hard for me to test code with `extern crate`s and I'd hate to let some error slip through. I'll add it when I have some time and a proper network.

Comment: @mcarton I almost forgot; I fixed the answer like you suggested.

Comment: [Let me help you not do work at work](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=0bf17d8ea1465e1a886f4caf254d17df&version=stable). Not all playgrounds are created equal ^_^.

Comment: @Shepmaster: <3